# Javascript function that updates fields of an object

Tags: javascript

What is the proper way to create a function that updates an object's fields? The way below, nothing seems to happen:

```
function adjmatrix(neighbors){
    this.neighbors = neighbors
    this.sum = 0
}

adjmatrix.prototype.update = function(){
    this.neighbors.forEach(function(a){a.sum += 10})
}

var myMatrix = new adjmatrix([1,2,3])
myMatrix.update()
print(myMatrix.sum) //Expect a value of 30, I get 0.
```

Kind of new to Javascript, so I'm not too clear on how scoping and stuff works. Thanks for your help. I am running my programming through `d8` in the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update the "sum" property of the object, your "update" method should look like this:

```
adjmatrix.prototype.update = function(){
    var matrix = this;
    this.neighbors.forEach(function(a){matrix.sum += 10})
}
```

If you wanted to sum up the "neighbors" values, it'd look like this:

```
adjmatrix.prototype.update = function(){
    var matrix = this;
    this.neighbors.forEach(function(a){ matrix.sum += a; })
}
```

The `.forEach()` call passes in each of the values of the array, one per call to the function.

Comment: Could you explain why I need to do `var matrix = this;`? Doesn't `this` refer to the function?

Comment: @goodcow no, `this` does not refer to the any function in this case. The details of how `this` works are somewhat involved, but here basically it's necessary to save the value of `this` as it stands when the "update" function is called, so that inside that little callback function the code can operate on the proper object.

Comment: @goodcow [here is a good Stackoverflow question on the subject of `this` and how it gets its values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: Why can't I do this.sum += 10? Why do I have to declare var self = this?

Comment: @goodcow Because `this` gets a value upon each function call, based on how that function call is made. You can write `this.sum`, but the value of `this` will not be the same as the value of `this` in the outer context of the "update" function. Read  that other question; this is a fundamental aspect of JavaScript semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have right now:

```
adjmatrix.prototype.update = function(){
    this.neighbors.forEach(function(a){a.sum += 10})
}
```

Tries to update the `sum` property of each element of the `neighbors` array, which means that it's trying to update the `sum` property of the *numbers* `1`, `2`, and `3`. This won't work since they don't have a `sum` property. Change your code to this:

```
adjmatrix.prototype.update = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.neighbors.forEach(function(a){ self.sum += 10; })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**ES5 reduce** method to avoid touching this.sum in every loop calls

```
adjmatrix.prototype.update = function(){
    this.sum = this.neighbors.reduce(function(memo, current) {
        return memo + current;
    }, 0);
}
```